Computing the PDF for joint density with a sum of independent RVs
I'm verifying an example in Bickel & Doksum, Vol 1 where the authors compute the PDF of a joint density in which both RVs are a weighted sum of standard normals.
The answer the authors come up with looks incorrect, and I'm wondering if I am making a mistake of if this is a case where the book's errata is incomplete.
The example is as follows. Let $W$ and $Z$ be independent standard normals and let $Y = Z + \theta W$ where $\theta > 0$. The authors write the joint PDF of $(Z, Y)$ as
$$
f(z, y ; \theta)
~=~ f(z) \, f(y|z ; \theta)
~=~ \phi(z) \cdot \theta^{-1} \cdot \phi\left((y-z)/\theta\right)
$$
where $\phi(x)$ is the PDF of the standard normal distribution, $X \sim N(0,1)$.
However, I'm wondering where the $\theta^{-1}$ comes from. It seems like the joint should just be $$
f(z, y ; \theta) ~=~ \phi(z) \cdot \phi\left((y-z)/\theta\right).\
$$
since $f(z) = \phi(z)$ and
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f(y|z;\theta)
&=& \Pr\{Y=y \,|\,Z=z\} \\
&=& \Pr\{W = (y - z)/\theta\} \\
&=& \phi((y - z)/\theta).
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Am I missing something? Thanks for any insights.

The authors expression is correct. Without the $\theta$ factor, $f(z,y;\theta)$ won't even integrate to $1$.

How does one derive the authors expression?

$\theta^{-1}$ factor comes from a simple change of variable.

Thanks, so it comes from applying the change of variables formula, $f_Y(y) = f_X\bigl(g^{-1}(y)\bigr),\Bigl|\frac{d}{dy}, g^{-1}(y)\Bigr|$
